# This error is misleading compared to the User Interface

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, ado.net

Error:

> Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

Now that's a popular question I managed to find online. Some have answers, some doesn't. Here is my issue. All I did was following a tutorial in a *Book from Microsoft Press*.. to connect to SQL Server database via Windows Authentication, then pull two fields from a table into a Form as textboxes as showed in the screen shot. It has `add, delete, update` buttons (automatically created).

[image]

Then it generates the following code, and points the error at `UPDATE` line. What I tried to do, update `ID = 2 to ID = 3`. There was no primary key in the table as I was trying out ADO.Net side compoents(connections/display and so on).

```
Private Sub Testdbtable1BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click
                (ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles
                                Testdbtable1BindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.Testdbtable1BindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.TestcmdDBDataSet) //-------<< error
End Sub
```

**So what's the real reason of having that `SAVE` or `UPDATE` button in the Form? Why can't it save my record change?**

Answer (score 0):

The tableadapter can not generate update logic when there is no primary key on the table. Add a PK, then go into the designer for the dataset and regenerate the queries. Make sure that INSERT and UPDATE queries have been generated this time.

Comment: In MSDN itself has a KB dedicated for using TableAdapter with exact above code in my question. So i am still not sure of what I am missung. Already spent more than a weej digging into this with all possible discussions out there. Still fruitless..

Comment: It's not your code. You must have a primary key on your table when the table adapter builds the queries at design time. Only when you have a primary key will it be able to build the full set of queries. In fact, you say yourself "There was no primary key in the table as I was trying out ADO.Net side compoents(connections/display and so on)." I'm sorry, I have no idea what this means. Without a primary key, it is impossible to identify the rows in your table